# Convert csv to excel not using a makro

Tags: excel, vb.net, solidworkspdmapi

I am working on a add-in for SolidWorks PDM, it should do the following:

Save BOM to CSV

Convert CSV to Excel

The first part is working, but the second part, where it should convert, is missing something and I can't figure out what.
The line where I open the csv-file `wb=Workbooks.Open()` has the following error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. This is why I have the filesystemobject in my code, but htat did not help.

Can anyone tell my what to do?

Thanks
Sussi

````
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports EdmLib
Imports Scripting


Module Module1

    Dim vault As IEdmVault20 = New EdmVault5
    Dim file As IEdmFile16
    Dim fold As IEdmFolder11
    Dim _fold As IEdmFolder11
    Dim bomFile As IEdmFile16
    Dim CurRev As String
    Dim bomMgr As IEdmBomMgr
    Dim bomView As IEdmBomView3

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim arrSize As Integer

    Dim csvName As String
    Dim excelName As String
    Dim Filepath As String

    Sub Main()
        vault.LoginAuto("ODIN", 0)
        fold = vault.RootFolder

        file = vault.GetFileFromPath("C:\ODIN\project\16xxx\16368 ODIN Engineering Slagelse Test af Solidworks og PDM\01 Drawings Parts and Assemblies\01 SW Files\16368.01.sldasm")
        _fold = vault.GetFolderFromPath("C:\ODIN\project\16xxx\16368 ODIN Engineering Slagelse Test af Solidworks og PDM\01 Drawings Parts and Assemblies\01 SW Files")

        CurRev = file.CurrentRevision
        Dim fileNameNoExt = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)

        csvName = "Temp_" + fileNameNoExt + "-Rev-" + CurRev + ".csv"

        'Get BOM Name "ODIN BOM", configuration "Default"
        bomMgr = vault.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_BomMgr)

        Dim ppoRetLayouts() As EdmBomLayout = Nothing
        Dim ppoRetLayout As EdmBomLayout

        bomMgr.GetBomLayouts(ppoRetLayouts)
        ppoRetLayout.mbsLayoutName = "ODIN BOM NAV info"

        bomView = file.GetComputedBOM(ppoRetLayout.mbsLayoutName, -1, "Default", 1)

        'Display BOM view row and column information
        Dim ppoRows() As Object = Nothing
        Dim ppoRow As IEdmBomCell
        bomView.GetRows(ppoRows)
        i = 0
        arrSize = ppoRows.Length
        str = ""
        While i < arrSize
            ppoRow = ppoRows(i)
            'bomFile = vault.GetFileFromPath(ppoRow.GetPathName)

            str = "BOM Row " & i & ": " & vbLf & "Item ID:" & ppoRow.GetItemID & vbLf & "Path name: " & ppoRow.GetPathName & vbLf & "Tree level: " & ppoRow.GetTreeLevel & vbLf & " Is locked? " & ppoRow.IsLocked
            'MsgBox(str)
            i += 1
        End While

        'bomView.SaveToCSV("C:\Users\sbi\Desktop\BOMtest\" + csvName, False)

        'Convert CSV to Xlsx
        excelName = fileNameNoExt + "-Rev-" + CurRev + ".xlsx"
        Filepath = "C:\Users\sbi\Desktop\BOMtest\"

        'Open csv-file
        Dim x As Object
        ' x = Shell("""explorer.exe"" ""C:\Users\sbi\Desktop\BOMtest\""" & csvName & """")

        Dim FSO As Object
        Dim csvFolder As Object

        FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        csvFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Filepath)

        Dim wb As Workbook

        wb = Workbooks.Open(csvFolder + csvName,, ";",,,,,,,,,,,,)
        wb.SaveAs("C:\Users\sbi\Desktop\BOMtest\" + excelName)
        wb.Close()

    End Sub


End Module```
````

Comment: Try this instead for that line: Dim wb As New Workbook

Comment: Is this VB.Net or VBA?

Comment: Where are you defining Workbooks.  Don't you need to be setting up an instance of Excel to do this?  Would also advise better options to deal with CSV and Excel documents rather than using office interop.  Check out the many 3rd party tools available via Nugets

Comment: I am using VBA.